# Get element in array just below matching value

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a simple ruby array and I want to select the element in the array just below the matching value.

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10]
```

The matching value I have is 10 but I want to be able to instead get the value before 10 which is 6.

```
numbers.some_magical_ruby_method {|n| n == 10} # I hope to return 6 since it's the element before 10
```

My question is what Ruby method exists for me to select the value before the matching value.

Comment: For unsorted array, such as `[1, 10, 6]` what should be returned: `1` or `6`?

Comment: It should return `1`.

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect this. BTW, what would be returned for `[1, 2, 3]` array and `10`?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Where did you get stuck? Is the array always sorted like in your example? Is the element to search for always in the back of the array or could it also be the first element? What should the return value be in that case? Is there always only one matching element? What should the return value be if there are multiple matching elements? Is there always going to be a matching element? What should the return value be if there isn't? What should the return value for an empty array be?

Comment: @Jörg, I'm sorry, I was distracted. Could you please repeat what you just said?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Array#take` with `Array#index`:

```
> numbers.take(numbers.index(10).to_i).last
=> 6
```

If a value is not found then the returned value is `nil`.

Comment: index() returns an integer so to_i is useless

Comment: @Maxxx not true if the object isn't found in the array, in which case it returns nil, the to_i changes nil to a 0, so the take invocation gives an empty array. The to_i is necessary to avoid a TypeError.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend Array class with this method

```
class Array
 def previous_element el
  each_cons(2) {|prev, curr| return prev if curr == el }
 end
end
```

Comment: Switch this to a break statement instead of return and you can do it inline without the method definition: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,10].each_cons(2) {|m, n| break m if n == 10}`

Comment: +1 for being the only quasi one-liner that avoids multiple loops or unnecessary memory consumption and/or complex conditionals

Comment: Not the fastest, but innovative. I'd prefer you not muck-up `Array`.

Answer (score 3):

```
numbers[numbers.index(10) - 1]
=> 6
```

Comment: f numbers dont have value 10, this code will produce error `undefined method - for nil:NilClass –`

Answer (score 2):

```
result = nil
index = numbers.index(10)
if index and index > 0
  result = numbers[(index - 1)]
end
result
# => 6
```

Comment: Welcome, PHP :) Ruby guidelines suggest to use postfix `if` notation here. Or, even better: `index = numbers.index(10) && index > 0 ? numbers[(index - 1)] : nil`.

Comment: Maybe you can use `result = numbers[(index - 1)] if index.to_i > 0`

Answer (score 2):

```
def number_before numbers, num
  idx = numbers.index(num)    
  return numbers[idx - 1] unless (idx.nil? || idx == 0)
  return nil
end

> numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10]
> number_before numbers, 10 #=> 6
> numbers = [1,2,3]
> number_before numbers, 10 #=> nil
> numbers = [1,10,6]
> number_before numbers, 10 #=> 1
> numbers = [10,6,1]
> number_before numbers, 10 #=> nil
```

Find the index of 10, and returning the previous element, or nil if the number is not found or previous element is not found. The idx == 0 case is important, because the array index -1 will wrap around to the front in ruby.

Comment: Maybe, you can use this `(idx.nil? || idx == 0) ? nil : numbers[idx - 1]`

Comment: Sure, @LukasBaliak - that's another way to do it - I just find mine a bit more readable - but that is one of the great subjective debates - brevity vs readability :-)

Comment: Hey, what's this? An answer that can be understood the first time through?

Answer (score 0):

```
def prev_nbr(numbers, nbr)
  n = nil
  enum = numbers.to_enum    
  loop do
    return n if enum.peek == nbr
    n = enum.next
  end
  nil
end

previous_nbr(numbers, 4) #=> 3
previous_nbr(numbers, 8) #=> nil
previous_nbr(numbers, 1) #=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer gives the result as the value of the element at the index before the requested value:

```
numbers[((arr_ind=numbers.index(10)).to_i > 0) ? arr_ind-1 : numbers.length]
```

This could also be written as this (using nil instead of the numbers[numbers.length] result):

```
((arr_ind=numbers.index(10)).to_i > 0) ? numbers[arr_ind-1] : nil
```

Neither of these solutions suffer the problem of "wrapping" found when used with the simple nil.to_i solutions or when the requested value is at the beginning of the array, such as when the value to search is 0 or not found in the array.  This solution avoids artificial looping and excess memory usage.

The only side effect is that the arr_ind variable is either created or overwritten if it already exists.

This short test demonstrates the results of searching for each of the numbers in the range (-1..13):

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10]

def answer(arr,element)
  arr[((arr_ind=arr.index(element)).to_i > 0) ? arr_ind-1 : arr.length]
end

answers = [nil, nil, nil, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, nil, nil, nil]

(-1..13).each_with_index do |number, i|
  puts "#{answer(numbers,number) == answers[i] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: #{number}"
end
```

The output from this test shows:

```
Pass: -1
Pass: 0
Pass: 1
Pass: 2
Pass: 3
Pass: 4
Pass: 5
Pass: 6
Fail: 7
Pass: 8
Pass: 9
Fail: 10
Pass: 11
Pass: 12
Pass: 13
```

"Pass" means that the test result meets expectations and passes; "Fail" means that it did not meet expectations.  Expected values are in the `answers` array, corresponding one-to-one with the values in the test range.